# How to exclude 'jar' file from External Library

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting `httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar` file with one of the `aar` file that I am adding in my dependencies.

I want to exclude this `jar` from this dependency, because this is giving me `duplicate` library error message.

I have tried many things, from

> ```
>  exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient-android'
> ```

to

> ```
>      {exclude module: "httpclient-android-4.3.5.1"}
> ```

but nothing is helping, the '.jar`file is still there and part of`SDK`

[image]

Comment: You tried doing `compile('lib:version') {exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient-android'}`

Comment: yes, i am trying this;  compile(name: 'MY-SDK-1.1.1', ext: 'aar')  { exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient-android' }

Comment: Are you trying to compile something from the ./libs folder? If so this link might be of interest https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/g1AiJM7PeVs

Comment: is the `aar` you're including made by you (assuming from the name `MY-SDK`)? or is it something exernal, made by a third-party?

Comment: Do you execute `clean` tasks between your attempts to clean-up the setup?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this also?:

```
configurations { all { exclude module: 'httpclient' exclude module: 'httpcore' } }
```

Comment: Ok, let me know what